# How do I tell vim to detect when a new file was created and do some action?

Tags: vimscript, autocmd

What I want to achieve is simply set up some auto command that will detect anytime I create a new file and based on the name of the file I want to insert a couple of lines of text in that file. So if the file name matches my string it will insert lines of text.

I know how to insert text if a new a file was created via `vim myfile` but if within vim I do `tabnew myfile` nothing happens.

Hope I was clear, thanks!

Comment: I’m not sure what happened to the earlier comment here, but you cannot append text to a tab, only to a buffer (memory-representation of textual content, usually linked to a file; may be displayed in one or more windows, which are be in one or more tapages). Can you please [edit] your question to more clearly specify what your goals are and what you’ve attempted?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I edited my question.

Comment: `I know how to insert text if a new a file was created via` Please, be more scrupulous. As for now, it looks like you're trying to do something with autocommands (an advanced topic), while not knowing what's a buffer name and filetype and how to change them (a basic topic). Also read `:h :tabnew` to see what's a proper syntax of this command.

Comment: @Matt no need to be so harsh; OP is trying to learn... we were all there at one time or another.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm not, or, at least, I don't intend to be. But I just don't get what is the question about even after the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first resource on files, buffers, tabs, etc., I recommend [this QA and the many links to be found there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26708822/4400820).

---

As for autocommands, they are indeed an advanced topic, so having a good grasp of the fundamentals is crucial. In particular, when you start editing a file in a new tab (such as via `:tabedit`), either `BufRead` or `BufNewFile` should fire ([Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html) has a great resource on autocommands, but I do recommend getting used to `:help` first).

So you can use something like

```
augroup MyGroup
  au!
  au BufRead,BufNewFile myPat normal! GAmy text
augroup END
```

You can also use the `append()`, though from mobile I don’t have the syntax offhand (something like `call append(line('$'), 'my text')`).

Lastly, if your specific filename is actually detected as a filetype, and you want to trigger for all filetypes, I would recommend reading about filetype-plugins. Start with the help, and then there are some great resources here (search ftplugin).

Comment: Thanks for giving me the syntax and suggesting the resources before I dabble with auto commands, Excellent answer!

Comment: Is myPat supposed to be a regex pattern?

Comment: @MosheRabaev not exactly—see `:help file-pattern`